# Writing to SD card via USB adapter - any race in it?

Tags: linux, usb

I've made some script for creation of SD card contents. It is creating partition table and filesystems, mounting it, copying files on it, syncing and then unmounting it. I noticed that sometimes there is problem with zero-length files. In details - some files on destination SD card are 0 length files.

I'm wondering if there is not any race in such situation. I mean: after I unmounted the filesystems - the user removes the SD card, Linux system has completed dumping buffers already but USB is still transmitting data.

Is it possible such a race? Any ideas how to avoid this issue? In other words - how can I ensure that when the system has completed dumping the buffers - the USB layer also finished it work?

Or maybe it is the problem with journal because the partition I'm copying the files is ext4?

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess that `sync` should not return whilst there is still data to be written over USB (or whatever); but that guess assumes that everything works perfectly. Do you have a feel for the exact circumstances that cause the problem? For example you say "the user removes the SD card" -- does the problem reproduce only if the SD card is removed?

Comment: The user uses my script for creating SD card and he is removing this SD card after the script ends. He has created about 20 such a cards and 3 of them have a few zero length files. To be honest I haven't watched when this user removes the cards, but I hope it is doing it just after script ends.